# How do I get alt text to support vertical-align: middle?

Tags: html, css

In the following test case, the alt text is horizontally centered, but it's stuck to the top of the box. How do I get it in the middle?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; border: solid black 1px;">
      <img src="asdfasdf" alt="foo" style="display: block; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One advantage of tables is they provide cross-browser vertical centering. DIVs don't. This is once case where I'd bite the bullet and add those ugly TRs and TDs.

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
   <tr>
     <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
       <img src="asdfasdf" alt="foo" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

It's called a *single-celled centering table* and ugly as it is, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using some spaces at the start of the alt attribute.  It was the only thing that seemed to work for me on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `display:table-cell` instead of `block`.

Comment: Nope. That actually breaks the horizontal align, too.